# Will Ubuntu 12.10 run with hardware acceleration on ZOTAC ZBOX HD-ID34 nVidia Ion?

Tags: nvidia

I'm contemplating buying this mini-PC [ZOTAC ZBOX HD-ID34](http://www.zotacusa.com/zbox-hd-id34-blu-ray.html)

I've read in some posts of issues with earlier releases of Ubuntu and wanted to makes sure that those issues have been resolved before I make a purchase I'll regret.  So my question is; Will this device run 12.10 and the coming 13.04 with hardware acceleration at install without much work needed?

Answer (score 0):

I have a ZOTAC Ion box, and while I can't guarantee that you won't have problems with this specific model, generally speaking Nvidia ION machines are well supported by the Nvidia drivers.